# How to customize the just the first line of a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, customization, except

I created a ListView whose entries are generated with a while on an SQLite query, except the first line that i write as i wanted in the code.

Here is the related XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

How to customize it to change font style only for the first line of the ListView?

Comment: Add a header view in code and assign it a custom layout.

Comment: I did it, now how to add content in it?

Comment: As usual, find the id of the TextView in your add layout, then use `setText()` to add the text you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

You can use listview header if you want to change style or layout of first row only

Comment: I add this code:         View headerView = ((LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.stat_list_header, null, false);
        lview.addHeaderView(headerView);

but nothing happens. How to fill in it now?

Comment: if you are having textView in customHeaderLayout(R.layout.stat_list_header), you can find its id like TextView tx = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.text_id); and then just do tx.setText("your text");